# Python Logging: How to pass logging level as an argument

Tags: python, logging

How can we pass logging level as an argument?

For example:

```
level1 = 'DEBUG'
level1lower = level1.lower()
logger.setLevel(logging.level1)
logger.level1lower('Some messages passed for logging's)
```

This is the closest representation of my problem coz I want to write one function that would take logging levels as argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `logger.log` instead of the methods that supply an implicit log level. You'll have to supply the integer logging level, though.

```
# Equivalent to logger.debug(msg)
level1 = 'DEBUG'
logger.log(getattr(logging, level1),  # Convert DEBUG to 10
           msg)
```